# Printing an array with a symbol next to it

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to print a '>' sign next to an array which is able to move up and down when different things are inputted.

I am able to print a 12x12 array of 0s but when I try to print a '>' in line 7, the '>' is inputted into the array and the row itself is shifted over instead of the array being kept uniform (i.e. the '>' must be independent to the array).

I have tried creating two arrays of the '>' and the 0s but I am not able to print two things horizontally next to each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int row = 0;
    while (row < 12){
        int col = 0;
        while (col < 12){
            
            printf(" 0");
            col = col + 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
        row = row + 1;
        if (row == 7) {
            printf(">");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

intended output:

```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

thank you !

Comment: For your desired output you need to print a space character before any row that isn't the row with the `>`.

Comment: I’ve tried that but how do I make the exception that “(if row doesn’t have ‘>’ printf “SPACE“)"

Comment: How about an `else`? I prefer `for` over `while`, but the concept is the same: https://godbolt.org/z/snv4WaazP

Answer (score 0):

To display a ">" sign before your matrix you can use a conditional statement specifically for the required line number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    if(i == 7)          // conditional statement 
        printf("> ");   // for ">" followed by 
    else                // a space to maintain
        printf("  ");   // the structure of matrix

    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        printf("0 ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!!!